# Ajax call using jQuery to String Controller method

Tags: ajax, spring, jquery, spring-mvc

I have the following Spring Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/accreq")
```

with the following mapping and file similar to `org.springframework.samples.mvc.ajax.account.AvailabilityStatus` with an extra boolean field `someBooleanValue`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/defRoles", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody AvailabilityStatus loadDefaultRoles(
    @RequestParam(value="idGroup", required=false) String groupID {
```

I'm trying to call this method with the following jquery ajax

```
$.getJSON("${pageContext. request. contextPath}/accreq/defRoles.htm", { idGroup: $('#infoGroup').val() }, function(availability) {
        if (availability.someBooleanValue) {
            //Do this
        } else {
            //Do else
        }
    });
```

Spring method is being executed but I get a `406` response back. What `dataType` I need to set to get a successful response? This use to work under `Spring 3.1.4` and now it does not work on higher version of Spring like `3.2.4` or `4.0.0`. In short, how to handle object return in Ajax response?

Response header - `406` Error

```
Request Headersview source
Accept  application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection  keep-alive
```

Config

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.X" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<cache:annotation-driven />
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>

<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="messages" />
</bean>
...mapping for controller.....database etc

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    <property name="cache"  value="true" />
    <property name="order"  value="1" />
</bean>
```

Comment: If I recall correctly the jQuery `getJSON` method is sending the data as JSON to the server and not as a request parameter. So basically your content send to the server is JSON whereas spring expects it to be a request parameter.

Comment: I feel the same but the method is getting invoked. The problem is more about the response. How should the response be formulated to escape `406` error?

Comment: How are you testing that the method is getting called? The response should be returning HTML as that is what you are requesting (you are calling a .htm URL which expects the content to be HTML).

Comment: Using breakpoint. After the ajax call I see the method stops at the debug point. So you are suggesting the returned String should be HTML type. But can I not specify the return type in `Ajax` call like  `dataType: "text",` or some other type for the object (if there exists any)? Wondering how this worked for 3.1.4?

Comment: Internally there has been quite an overhaul. I'm saying that the response request for json (probably) but the extension (.htm) leads spring to believe that it must return HTML. They don't match so it doesn't know what to do, can you post your configuration. You might want to read this section of [the Spring Reference Guide](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-content-negotiation)

Comment: Have added the config. If you need more do let me know. Thanks for pointing me to the guide. I will try to change the return from `object` to `HTML content`.

Comment: Is that **ALL** mvc related setup? I would expect a `<mvc:annotation-driven />` somewhere.

Comment: Added (updated) more. If there is something specific you are looking for then please let me know.

Comment: Small comment about your configuration, the `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` is already registered by the use of `<context:component-scan .. />`. Saves you a line of xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Spring 3.2 there was an overhaul of the content-negotiation implementation. With it there was a [ContentNegotiationManager](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/accept/ContentNegotiationManager.html) introduced and with it also the fact that the path takes precedence over the Accept-Header. (Using the Accept-Header in a crossbrowser compatible way is quite a pain as different browsers send different headers :s).

As I mentioned in one of the comments [the reference guide](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-content-negotiation) clearly documents how one can configure the `ContentNegotiationManager`.

Something like the following should fix things

```
<mvc:annotation-driven content-negotiation-manager="contentNegotiationManager" />
<bean id="contentNegotiationManager" class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="favorPathExtension" value="false" />
</bean>
```